# how can you determine location of <script> tag from inside said tag?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out the location of the script tag the current javascript is running in. What is really going on is that I need to determine from *inside* a src'd, dynamically inserted javascript file where it is located in the DOM.   These are dynamically generated tags; code snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>where am i?</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function byId(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function create_script(el, code) {
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.text = code;
      el.appendChild(script);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="find_me_please"></div>
  <script>
    create_script(byId("find_me_please"), "alert('where is this code located?');");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you figure this out?  I'm struggling with the same issue...

Answer (score 5):

You could give the script an id tag, [like this dude does](http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2008/01/09/dom-for-hackers/)...

Comment: wow, awesome stuff!  only problem is that I will not be able to know the id from inside the code... (usually it is src'd)... I /can/ have code inside the src'd js script, but without that knowledge... unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

You can use document.write to create a dummy DOM object and use parentNode to escape out. For example:

```
<script>
(function(r) {
  document.write('<span id="'+r+'"></span>');
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var here_i_am = document.getElementById(r).parentNode;
    ... continue processing here ...
  });
})('id_' + (Math.random()+'').replace('.','_'));
</script>
```

This assumes you don't actually have control of the `<script>` tag itself, such as when it's inside a `<script src="where_am_i.js"></script>` - if you *do* have control of the `<script>` tag, simply put an ID on it, as in:

```
<script id="here_i_am">...</script>
```

Comment: cannot do document.write ... in fact that is part of the reason for asking :)

Comment: Why can't you do document.write?

Comment: my js is inserted after the dom has completed

Answer (score 0):

If you are just running this on page load, this works

```
<script>
  var allScripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  var thisScript = allScripts[allScripts.length];
  alert(thisScript);
</script>
```

Comment: yup, but unfortunately I am not running it onload... coming up with a better explanation of what I'm trying to do :)

Thanks though, useful for many other situations!