# Is there a way to detect where in a DOM structure sits my script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I wonder if is there any possibility to check when in dom structure my script initialli sits ei.

```
<html><head></head><body>
<div id=test><script src="https://myscript.com?id=5215"></script></div>
</body></html>
```

So again: Can I write some code inside this script to detect where in DOM node script sits and for example create some extra HTML tags right before script tag if e.i script has been pasted at the end of body tag?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please explain it with an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can you determine location of <script> tag from inside said tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401463/how-can-you-determine-location-of-script-tag-from-inside-said-tag)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402158/1427878) in the duplicate explains how to do that for script elements that are set to execute “in place”, and not loaded asynchronously or deferred ...

Comment: Well let's assume someone pasting script tag anywhere in the dom. Can the script know where it sits in a dom?